# Cache issues embedding multiple bundled react-native applications in iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, react-native

I'm trying to run multiple ReactNative applications within a single Objective-C app. I wrote a little bundle script, very similar to react-native-xcode.sh. The only difference is that mine is based off the input and output files supplied by the user:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$CONFIGURATION" in
  Debug)
    DEV=true
    ;;
  Release)
    DEV=false
    ;;
  "")
    echo "$0 must be invoked by Xcode"
    exit 1
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Unsupported value of \$CONFIGURATION=$CONFIGURATION"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

# For the number of input files, get the input file name and corresponding output file name, and
# create a static bundle.
for (( i=0; i<$SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_COUNT; i++ ))
do
  eval INPUT_FILE_NAME=\${SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_$i}
  eval OUTPUT_FILE_NAME=\${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_$i}

  echo $INPUT_FILE_NAME
  echo $OUTPUT_FILE_NAME

  $(which react-native) bundle \
    --entry-file $INPUT_FILE_NAME \
    --dev $DEV \
    --platform ios \
    --bundle-output $OUTPUT_FILE_NAME

done
```

I have ReactNative applications specified in my package.json and installed using npm install. I specify the path to my input and output files in the Run Script build phase:
[image: Input and Output files of the "Run Script" phase]

For whatever reason, my bundle is never updated after npm install.

Code:
[image: Code at bundle time]

Bundle:
[image: Output after bundle]

FWIW, the package, before being installed, did have a text component reading "Choose Subscriptions".

It seems as if the `react-native bundle` command is using a cached file or Xcode is copying an old version of the `.jsbundle` to the application bundle each time. Does anyone know how to resolve the issue and have Xcode copy the correct `.jsbundle` to the application bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Known issue right now. Use either of these methods:

- Before each build: `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*`
- Add this option to your build script: `--resetCache true`

Comment: I don't see a `--resetCache` option on `react-native bundle`, unless it's hidden in the source. I tried running `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*` before my `bundle.sh` script was invoked, but that didn't work.

Comment: @HighFlyingFantasy here is the code for resetCache: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/b838b4617c05fa19a44ec21f1e27961b64efb210/local-cli/server/runServer.js#L68

Comment: Perhaps you are using an old version of RN. This is a documented issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4289